# Make body background image act as link

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've read many things online but I haven't found a way to make it work..

What I want:

I have a body background image and I was asked to make it a link as an advertisement.. The problem is that whatever I tried makes the whole page a link, whereas I want only the background of the webpage to act as a link. Is it possible,through html and css? Or even with use of javascript? Any solution is accepted... I'm stuck..Thanks in advance!

Comment: WOHOOO, and people without keyboard navigation can not use your ad! WIN!

Comment: From a usability standpoint, this sounds pretty terrible.  However you implement it, it's going to capture all sorts of clicks:  misclicks, highlighting for copying purposes, etc.

Comment: It's not my wish to implement it like that,but my employers' and his client..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't have the background image be the link. You can use JS to catch all clicks that are on the body, but not on one of its children

```
// This is not cross browser, that would be a separate question
document.body.onclick = function(e) {
  if (e.target === document.body) {
      window.location = "link.html"
  }
}
```

You can use jQuery for a cross browser version

```
$('body').click(function(e){
    if (e.target === this) {
        window.location = "link.html"
    }
});
```

If you want to give the background the cursor appearance, you can apply the following CSS

```
body {
   background-image: url(http://www.blutest.com/sites/default/files/butterfly2_large_0.jpg);
   cursor: pointer;
}

body, html {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
}

body * {
  cursor: default;
}
​
```

See it in action [here](http://jsfiddle.net/BcqBB/)

Comment: This doesn't work,it doesn't make body clickable,although I put cursor:pointer, the appropriate cursor appears (to the whole page - i want only to background) but you can't click the body..

Comment: This does work... you're not understanding what it does... The body is clickable, but it's not a link, so the hand cursor doesn't show. If you want the hand cursor, you have to add  `cursor:pointer` the to the body and then remove it from the top level children. See update to the answer

Comment: The only problem I can see here is that  if you have a div in the middle having some basic text, this part will be also linkable. How can you just link the background without linking the content in a div which is centered.

Comment: @ReneZammit I don't know what you mean Here's an example with text in a div that's not clickable... http://jsfiddle.net/BcqBB/10/ In the original example, you can observe the same thing since you can click on the images and nothing happens

Comment: @ReneZammit If you mean a div with a background, and you want just the background to be clickable, then that's not part of this question. This question is specifically about a body background image. There are many things (along the same lines) that would achieve the same goal. You should ask a new question if that's what you're trying to do (If you do, create a link to it from here)

Answer (score 2):

Using jQuery you can detect if the event was on the body directly:

```
$('body').on('click', function(e) {
    if( e.target != this ) return;
    window.location = 'http://google.com';
});
```

Answer (score 1):

DON'T.

This is an extremely annoying and universally hated practice. Users should be able to click on "the white" (*) without surprising effects.

I actually found your question while googling for ways to block this nasty "human exploit", and **I vow to forever boycott any vendor that advertises this way**.

(*) Of course the metaphorical notion of "the white" includes any area outside the main layout (or below the content of a sidebar if the sidebar is shorter than the main column) regardless of whether this area is white, solid color, or has a background image.

Answer (score 0):

Nope here
keep a page division inside the body dvision

add onclick to body and onclick to page too,

in the page on click add `event.stopPropagation()`